# SQL - Combining information with similar primary key/ID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know this question was asked before but the solution given for that question did not work for me. I couldn't write a comment stating my problem as I needed 50 reputation.

**Details:**

Oracle version 10g

**Solution Provided:**

```
select book_id,
       'Total Hours of Loan: ' || to_char(sum(hours_of_loan)) || chr(10) || 
       lpad('-', 30, '-')      || chr(10) ||
       xmlagg(xmlelement(x, descr, chr(10) || lpad('-', 30, '-') || chr(10)).extract('//text()')
                         order by date_of_loan)  as book_description
from   (
         select book_id, date_of_loan, hours_of_loan,
                'Written by: '      || checked_by                          || chr(10) ||
                'Date of Loan : '   || to_char(date_of_loan, 'mm/dd/yy')   || chr(10) ||
                'Hour(s) of Loan: ' || to_char(hours_of_loan)              || chr(10) ||
                'Comments: '        || comments                            || chr(10) ||
                'Student: '         || student      as descr
         from   student_book
       )
group by book_id
order by book_id
;
```

I tried creating a **dummy table** with **fake data** to test out the logic to see if it works for me and it does. But when I used the query for my **real data**, it prompted out an error that says:

> ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits

**ERROR prompted**

[image]

After reading about it, I found that it was because my data was too large.

**I tried creating table and a query to call from it**

```
DECLARE
  sSUM_TEXT  CLOB;
  sBOOK_ID VARCHAR2(10):= '1';
  nCount     NUMBER:=1;
BEGIN
  FOR rRECORDRec IN(SELECT BOOK_ID, CHECKED_BY, DATE_OF_lOAN, HOURS_OF_LOAN, COMMENTS, STUDENT  
                        FROM STUDENT_BOOK
                        WHERE BOOK_ID = '1')
  LOOP
    IF nCount != 1 THEN
      sSUM_TEXT := sSUM_TEXT||chr(10)||
                'Written by: '      || rRECORDRec.checked_by                 || chr(10) ||
                'Date of Loan : '   || rRECORDRec.date_of_loan               || chr(10) ||
                'Hour(s) of Loan: ' || rRECORDRec.hours_of_loan              || chr(10) ||
                'Comments: '        || rRECORDRec.comments                   || chr(10) ||
                'Student: '         || rRECORDRec.student                    || chr(10) ||
                '--------------------------------';
    ELSE
      sSUM_TEXT :=  'Written by: '      || rRECORDRec.checked_by                 || chr(10) ||
                    'Date of Loan : '   || rRECORDRec.date_of_loan               || chr(10) ||
                    'Hour(s) of Loan: ' || rRECORDRec.hours_of_loan              || chr(10) ||
                    'Comments: '        || rRECORDRec.comments                   || chr(10) ||
                    'Student: '         || rRECORDRec.student                    || chr(10) ||
                '--------------------------------';
    END IF;
    nCount := nCount + 1;
  END LOOP;

  INSERT INTO COMMENTS_SUMMARY(BOOK_ID,SUM_TEXT)
  VALUES (sBOOK_ID,sSUM_TEXT);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

This did not really solve my problem but it combined all the "COMMENTS" which had that specific BOOK_ID but without format

**Tried Solution**

```
select book_id,
       'Total Hours of Loan: ' || to_char(sum(hours_of_loan)) || chr(10) || 
       lpad('-', 30, '-')      || chr(10) ||
       xmlagg(xmlelement(x, descr, chr(10) || lpad('-', 30, '-') || chr(10)).extract('//text()')
                         order by date_of_loan) as book_description
from   (
         select book_id, date_of_loan, hours_of_loan,
                to_clob('Written by: '  || checked_by                 || chr(10) ||
                'Date of Loan : '       || date_of_loan               || chr(10) ||
                'Hour(s) of Loan: '     || hours_of_loan              || chr(10) ||
                'Comments: '            || comments                   || chr(10) ||
                'Student: '             || student)      as descr
         from   student_book
       )
group by book_id
order by book_id;
```

*The same error prompted out*

**2nd SELECT Statement**

I tried running the query separately. I ran the 2nd SELECT Statement for my **real data** and no errors were prompted even without the *TO_CLOB*

```
select book_id, date_of_loan, hours_of_loan,
                    'Written by: '  || checked_by                 || chr(10) ||
                    'Date of Loan : '       || date_of_loan               || chr(10) ||
                    'Hour(s) of Loan: '     || hours_of_loan              || chr(10) ||
                    'Comments: '            || comments                   || chr(10) ||
                    'Student: '             || student      as descr
             from   student_book
             order by book_id
           )
    --group by book_id
    order by book_id;
```

[image]

**My Question:**

How may I overcome this problem and group the data base on their ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably at least a few books for which you have too many loans, so the string built in XMLAGG is longer than 4000 characters. So you have to deal with CLOBs.

You need to add `.getclobval()` here:

```
... order by date_of_loan).getclobval() as book_description
```

It is possible that even the text for one "loan" is already too long (more than 4000 characters). This is a problem for concatenation - if all the inputs are less than 4000 characters Oracle treats them as VARCHAR2 and expects the result to also be VARCHAR2 (no more than 4000 characters). To "force" it to treat everything as CLOBs, it suffices to make the first input a CLOB.

Instead of `'Written by: '` (find it in the code) use

```
... to_clob('Written by: ')
```

Comment: Hey @mathguy, thank you for your reply but the same error still prompted out when I used it for my real table. But when I used it for the dummy table its still fine. Could it be because the "**Comments**" part of my real table is too large? Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: @ mathguy I was looking though the older question and I'm not sure about her/him but for me I am require to write the query for an assignment. I know I shouldn't ask questions about homework but I'm really stuck here. Sorry

Comment: Ah... OK. Assignments are ok on Stack Overflow, by the way, all we ask is that people show what they tried and where they ran into problems. Which you did, so that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding @mathguy. I've tried creating a table with the combined data and query to call from it. I have edited my question to show my query.

Comment: Oh - Perhaps even ONE "loan" results in text that is too long? I'll edit the answer to explain how to deal with that.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply as I was out. I tried adding in the _TO_CLOB_ and the same error appeared. I edited my question a bit. And also sorry for the trouble and thanks for making the effort to help.